# Java FX "mass" handling Buttons

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have started a TicTacToe project in Java FX using SceneBuilder.
The FXML consists simply in a 3x3 grid of buttons inside a `GridPane`.

What I would like to do is to make a "universal" method so that when one of the buttons is pressed, it changes its text to "O" or "X", granted that it has not yet been assigned to either one.

Something like this

```
private void onButtonClick(){
    if (btn00.getText() == null)
        btn00.setText("X or O");
}
```

where `btn00` is not the specific name of a button, but the one that is selected, as `someTableView.getSelectionModel()`... works for `TableView`s.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all those buttons have the `onButtonClick` method registered as the `onAction` event handler, you can add a `ActionEvent` parameter and retrieve the `Button` from the `source` property.

```
private void onButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    if (button.getText() == null || button.getText().isEmpty()) {
        button.setText("X or O");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Still, is there a way to "group" buttons so that, for instance, I can check if they all have text in them?

Comment: They are all children of the same `GridPane` aren't they? Use `GridPane.getChildren()`.

Comment: Actually, the Buttons are inside AnchorPanes that are inside the GridPane

Answer (score 1):

As well as the solution using `event.getSource()`, you can also just create a method that attaches a handler to a button:

```
private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3] ;
private String currentTurn = "O" ;

// ...

for (int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y < 3 ; y++) {
        buttons[x][y]=new Button();
        attachHandler(buttons[x][y]);
    }
}

// ...


private void attachHandler(Button button) {
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        if (button.getText()==null || button.getText().isEmpty()) {
            button.setText(currentTurn);
        }
    });
}
```